# completely ignore lines that start with a specific pattern

Tags: awk, string

I have a script which analyzes the output of a computation software.
sometimes the output comes with some extra data that are irrelevant to my script.
This data can be huge and makes running my simple script become seriously slow.

My script is in awk/bash.

I was wondering if it's possible to tell awk to completely ignore the lines after a specific pattern.

for example:

```
GOOD STUFF
----------------
IRRELEVENT DATA
----------------
IGNORE ALL THESE
----------------
END OF IT
----------------
GOOD STUFF
```

I was also wondering if I tell awk to look for lines starting with a specific pattern, would it ignore whatever comes after and speed up the script?

Comment: Just ignore those lines... e.g. `/pattern1/,/pattern2/{next}`but please post expected result or try to describe more accurately what you're trying to do there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To ignore some lines on a line-by-line basis, add `/unwanted pattern/ {next}` or `! /wanted pattern/ {next}` at the beginning of the script.

Alternatively, filter with grep: `grep -v 'unwanted pattern' | awk …` or `grep 'wanted pattern' | awk …`. This may be faster if grep eliminates a lot of lines, because grep is typically faster than awk for the same task (grep is more specialized so it can be optimized for its task; awk is a full programming language, it can do a lot more but it's less efficient).

If you want to ignore a block of consecutive lines, awk has a convenient facility for that: add `/^IRRELEVENT DATA/,/^END/ {next}` at the top of the script to ignore all lines starting with `IRRELEVENT DATA` (*sic*) and the following lines until the first line that starts with `END`. You can't do that with grep; you can do it with sed (`sed '/^IRRELEVENT DATA/,/^END/d' | awk …`) but it's less likely to be a performance gain than grep.

Comment: The awk range syntax is (also) comma, not two dots, and for sed you need the command `d`. Not relevant here, but in general awk can match start,end on the same (single) line while sed can't.

Comment: At last!... something that's easier to [grok](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grok) than ***negative lookahead***.

Answer (score 9):

Without using next, using negation instead.

Input:

```
$ cat f.txt
GOOD STUFF
----------------
IRRELEVENT DATA
----------------
IGNORE ALL THESE
----------------
END OF IT
----------------
GOOD STUFF
```

I want to ignore lines starting with the string "IRRELEVENT" or "IGNORE" or "END":

```
$ awk '!/^(IRRELEVENT|IGNORE|END)/' f.txt
GOOD STUFF
----------------
----------------
----------------
----------------
GOOD STUFF
```